7943 7943 I flutter : Login failed: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)
After publishing my app to google playstore, the above error appears in the adb logcat during the google login of the app, but the google login of the released apk works without any problem.
(None of the authentication functions work in playstore published app)
I have the google play console "app signing key certificate" sha1 fingerprint pasted correctly in firebase.
build.gradle
buildscript {
     ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.20' // Use the latest stable version

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'

ext {
compileSdkVersion = 34
targetSdkVersion = 34
appCompatVersion = "1.7.0"
}

subprojects { afterEvaluate { android { compileSdkVersion 34 } } }
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}

subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

app/build.gradle
signingConfigs {
        signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] 
            ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    }
   buildTypes {
       release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
          
       }
   }

